# How to get a property using reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

I need to remove any reference to `System.Data.SqlClient` from my project. The only instance I use it is to get a list of errors, for example:

```
if (ex is SqlException)
{
    var spx = ex as SqlException;
    if (spx.Errors != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < spx.Errors.Count; i++)
        { 
            var sqlError = spx.Errors[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Is the only alternative to use `Reflection` and call `GetProperty` as in:

```
if (ex.GetType().Name == "SqlException")
{
    var errors = ex.GetType().GetProperty("Errors");
    if (errors != null)
    {}
}
```

Comment: Wich client are you using isntead to access the Database? Why not look what it's Exceptions are?

Comment: @Christopher I'm using `System.Data.SqlClient` but data access is in a separate project. I need to remove the reference from this particular project so that I can pack it as a nuget package (for internal distribution) and having no additional dependencies because it will be used in .Net Core 2.2+ apps and it's resulting in a lot of errors.

Comment: That hoenstly sounds like a XY Problem. "I got errors, so I remove something I use and end up having to use reflection..."

Comment: @Christopher What's my other alternative then?

Comment: Ask for help how to properly solve those errors? I ahve no idea what solution there is, but this sounds *very much* like a wrong way. I have some other issues with your code, btw. I make a answer for that part at least.

Comment: Why you don't want to use reflection?

Comment: @VadimBondaruk Who has reflection as their first choice? And what do I need to do to fix that persons behavior? Reflection is a fallback. Do not use it, if you can avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a question of Exception handling. First, there is one list of [classifications](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/) and one set of [good guidelines](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET). Those two helped me and I consider them "required reading" on the thematic.

A lot of the stuff you are doing there looks pretty critical. You catch way to wide. Then filter by type using is. But you never throw the wrong exceptions on.

Your main worry seems to be code calling your code having to deal with `SqlException`, as adding teh Reference is for some reason not useable. Usually the solution is to make your own Exception Class and put the Sql one into inner Exception. The guidelines above have all the details I could give you on that.